# How to create a time counter without using Sleep()?

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to create a time counter that would count from 120 minutes and down. I thought about using `Sleep()` but I have found out that `Sleep()` is not accurate (so maybe the countdown would take 122 minutes instead of 120 minutes!). What other alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sleep(120*3600*1000)` is sufficiently accurate, that's going to take 120 minutes and perhaps a few milliseconds more.

You get a problem if you try to sleep repeatedly for one minute at a time, as the overruns accumulate. This is solvable by checking how long you overslept so far (compare the initial `time()` and the current `time()` values, modulo one minute). In this way, you occasionally may sleep for 59 seconds instead of one minute.

Comment: I intend to `Sleep()` one second at a time (to display the countdown progress in seconds to the user).

Comment: Now that I think about it, calling `printf()` (or some other function) would also add delay (but I guess it would be negligible)!

Comment: Well, in that case you'll need to check milliseconds. See [`GetLocalTime()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950(v=vs.85).aspx). You'll probably need to sleep about ~ 990 ms per iteration.

Comment: If you need to check periodically in order to update a UI, it will be simpler to always sleep a fixed amount. Simply save the time when the whole process started, then on each cycle simply compare the current time against the start time to see if you need to stop. I usually set the sleep period around 100ms. It makes for a responsive UI and reasonable accuracy.

Comment: @Ferruccio You mean I should use the system clock? This is a great idea actually (it would give me almost perfect accuracy), but if the user change the system clock then my program will be broken (not a big issue though, as the vast majority of users don't have a reason to do that!).

Comment: You could use the system clock. You could use GetTickCount(), which simply returns the number of ticks since boot time (be careful though, it rolls over every 49 days, but that's easy to compensate for). If you have Boost available, Boost.Timer makes it dead simple to create a simple elapsed time counter.

Answer (score 2):

SetTimer, and then handle the WM_TIMER message.

Comment: It's not necessarily any more accurate than `Sleep()`. If you've got higher priority messages in the queue then its delivery will be delayed.

Comment: @Sean: `SetTimer` with a delay of 1000 ms is sufficiently accurate for the intended purpose (a countdown displaying the current remainder in minutes and seconds). Since the base/starting time is known, the parameter could also be adjusted whenever `WM_TIMER` is handled.

Comment: @IInspectable - I think you'll find `Sleep()` is also acceptable given the same delay. Also, the question doesn't mention that there's a window available to post the WM_TIMER to. Having to create a window just to post to it is crazy.

Comment: @Sean: `Sleep` implies a second thread. Creating a message-only window to handle messages is anything but crazy.

Comment: @IInspectable - no, it doesn't. And if you look at the accepted answer you'll see that the poster is going to use `Sleep()` without any mention of an additional thread. Besides, what if the program is a console app or a service? Also, if you add a window you'll need to be processing the message queue to make it work, which over-complicates the solution.

Comment: @Sean: How do you propose to address the requirement *"to display the countdown **progress** in seconds to the user"* using the accepted answer without another thread?

Comment: @IInspectable - you have no idea about the architecture of the applicaton, so to assume it needs to add another thread to handle the shutdown output is wrong. It could be a console application that's spun of another thread to do its processing, and the main thread is just sat there waiting for the user to request an exit. Once they do it signals the thread to stop and then starts `Sleep()`ing for 1000ms blocks in a loop, outputting progress while it wait for a clean shutdown. Simple..!

Comment: @Sean: Changing the accepted answer to make your comment sound right? That desperate? Really?

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what you really want to do here are some ways you can do it:

1. Use a clock from std::chrono to constantly check the current time. High_resolution or steady_clock are good candidates. You might want to yield your thread to reduce the busy-wait effects on your CPU.
2. Go exotic and use a std::conditional_variable that does a wait_until( time_point ) on a pre-locked mutex. It will never get to lock the mutex so will time-out after your desired time.
3. The same trick as 2. but with a WaitForSingleObject instead.